# How can I calculate the amount of hours in a duration that exceeds 24hours?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice

I've got a value of `[HH]:MM:SS` that is `76:30:00`. I'd like to convert this value to a decimal value of the 'number' of hours - in this case 76.5.

However `HOURS()` returns 4 instead of 76. Probably because `(3*24 + 4)=76`

I'm using Libre Office Calc - but I assume it would be the same solution with Excel.

Comment: The same seems to happen in excel as well. `=INT(A1)*24+HOUR(A1)` returns value you need. Not sure if that is available in libreoffice.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your regional settings this works at least in excel...

American, with regional settings "hh:mm:ss" and delimiter "`,`"

```
=TEXT(H15,"[h]:mm:ss")*24
```

European, with regional settings "tt:mm:ss" and delimiter "`;`"

```
=TEXT(H15;"[t]:mm:ss")*24
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores dates/times as days and fractions of a day, usually since 1/1/1900.

So all you need to do is multiply your time value by 24, and format the result as `General` or as `Number with 1 (or more) decimals`.